# Check for empty string is failing in js

Tags: javascript, undefined, string

After splitting a set of glossary terms with:

```
lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

I then iterate through the array and parse out each term to properly format them during output. However, a simple check for empty strings has become much more of a headache than I could've ever imagined. Console logging gives me this:

```
...
"Pushing" "dyspnea: Labored or difficult respiration." //correct
"Pushing" ""
...
```

Things I have tried in order to find these empty strings:

```
line === ""
line.length == 0
if(line)
isNaN(line.charCodeAt(0))
typeof line == "undefined"
```

And various combinations of the list above. On recommendation from a coworker, I checked the line endings of the input text, but it all seemed normal.

I'm sure I'm just doing something *really* stupid, but the solution has eluded me for far too long. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**
Thanks for the suggestions everyone. Alas, the problem persists...

Also, I forgot to mention, but I have tried both trimming and replacing whitespace in each line after the split, but came up with nothing.

As requested, here is more relevant code.

```
var text = "";
var end = /\x2E\s\x5B/gm; // ". ["
var lines = [];
var terms = [];

text = document.getElementById("terms").value;
lines = text.split(/[\r\n]+/);
parseText();

function parseText() {
    var i = 0;
    while(i < lines.length) {
        var line = lines[i];
        endIndex = lines[i].search(end);

        if(line != "" || line != " " || line.length != 0 ) {
            parseTerm(lines[i].substring(0, endIndex+1));
        }

        i++;
}
```

Comment: Can we see a complete code example which reproduces the issue? Your empty checks should work.

Comment: @Vache More relevant code has been added. Let me know if you see anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that in my input there was a line with two spaces. I have NO idea why this was causing problems, considering the split was specifically on the pattern described above, but replacing instances of too much whitespace fixed the issue. The new line:

```
text.replace(/\s\s+/g, " ").split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answer stated issue is probably whitespace, you can use the trim function to shorten your code:

```
if (line.trim() == "") {
    alert("Blank");
}
```

Comment: No dice. Same output.

Comment: it's not resolve problem, then spaces inside text "Hello   World!"

Answer (score 0):

maybe string is not a "", but " "?

so check not only zero length, but "white space"

```
if(st1 == "" || st1 == " " || st1.length == 0 ){
    console.log("find empty")    
}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `st1.trim() === ""`

Comment: A good thought, I hadn't looked into this much, but still nothing.